# ajaxform giving me wrong response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having below form that login to instagram depends on the response, if it loggin means "ok", then success, if not it should giving me else state.

but in my case below it always giving me null state for some reasons.

i've tried to play around it with failed attempt.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#msform").ajaxForm({
                beforeSubmit: function(data, frm, opt) {
                    $("#login_submit").css('background', '#A3D780');
                    $("#login_submit").enable(false);
                    $('#divMsg').html('Doing the magic, please wait!');
                    return true;
                },
                success: function(response, statusText) {
                    $("#login_submit").css('background', '#66bd2b');
                    $("#login_submit").enable(true);

                    if(response == null) {
                        $('#divMsg').html("Service is not available at this moment, Please try later. Sorry for inconvenience. Thank you.");
                    } else {
                        if(response.status == 'ok') {
                            $("#msform").html('<fieldset><p class="form-field input-label" style="padding-bottom: 15px">Thank you! Your request is being processed. Your order should arrive within 3-5 business days!</p></fieldset>')
                        } else {
                            $('#divMsg').html(response.message);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function(a, b) {
                    $('#divMsg').html("Service is not available at this moment, Please try later. Sorry for inconvenience. Thank you.");
                    $("#login_submit").css('background', '#66bd2b');
                    $("#login_submit").enable(true);
                }       
            });
            $("#tos").click(function() {
                setLoginState();
            });

            $("#insta_id").keyup(function() {
                setLoginState();
            });

            $("#insta_pwd").keyup(function() {
                setLoginState();
            });
        });

        function setLoginState() {
            var checked = $("#tos").is(":checked");
            var input = $("#insta_id").val().trim() != '' && $("#insta_pwd").val().trim() != '';

            if (checked && input) {
                $("#login_submit").css('background', '#66bd2b');
                $("#login_submit").enable(true);
            }
            else {
                $("#login_submit").css('background', '#A3D780');
                $("#login_submit").enable(false);
            }
        }
```

Success response:

```
{"logged_in_user": {"pk": 6766480367, "username": "10710prince", "full_name": "prince 10710", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/25013607_519746415057631_6753099211190829056_n.jpg", "profile_pic_id": "1673236351150247137_6766480367", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "is_business": false, "can_see_organic_insights": false, "show_insights_terms": false, "allow_contacts_sync": true, "phone_number": "+917708088101", "country_code": 91, "national_number": 7708088101}, "status": "ok"}
```

Failed response:

```
{"message": "The password you entered is incorrect. Please try again or log in with Facebook.", "status": "fail", "error_type": "bad_password"}
```

Backend:

```
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $loginResult = json_decode($response);

        $file = 'somefile.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $response . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        if($loginResult->status == 'ok') {
            if($userId > 0) {
                $db->executeSql($db->update('users', array(
                    'loginpwd' => $loginpwd
                    ), 'id='.$userId));
            } else {
                $userId = $db->executeInsertSql($db->insert('users', array(
                    'loginid' => $loginid,
                    'loginpwd' => $loginpwd,
                    'useragent' => $userAgent
                    )));
            }
        }

        return $loginResult;
    }
}
?>
```

But my code above always giving me response state Null for some reason?

what am doing wrong exactly?, can somebody point to the bug, issue?

thank you,
regards

Comment: It seems there is no issue with your js code.Try to put your backend implementation codes.

Comment: Done, updated, please take a look the part of the response.

Comment: @faizunnabi done, please take a look buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing these :

1. instead of return use echo for the response
2. send the response without json_decode and try the decoding on frontend using JSON.parse function.

   $response=curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   //$loginResult = json_decode($response);

   echo $response; //replaced with return $response

Hope it helps !